# Android "Error generating final archive: Failed to add .../bin/resources.ap_"

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

In Android SDK 16, Android NDK 7, Eclipse Helios 3.6.2, on Mac OS X 10.6.8:

I made a couple of small changes to the C++ source and one asset file of my Android native code project, and now all of a sudden it refuses to run in the Android emulator.

The build itself generates no error messages, but whenever I try to run it, I get a dialog saying "Your project contains error(s), please fix them before running your application." And the following error message suddenly appears in the "Problems" tab:

Error generating final archive: Failed to add /Users/cfry/src/Plexil-android/workspace/Plexil-android/bin/resources.ap_

No files were added and no build or run settings were changed prior to the error appearing. Nor were there any new updates to Eclipse or the Android SDK/NDK. Just a couple of source file edits.

I have tried cleaning and rebuilding, and relaunching Eclipse, and none of this seems to help.

A Google search on the error message text failed to turn up any suggestions.

This is a showstopper. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a symptom of a failing hard drive.